# Xamarin Forms - Duplicate Screens

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm writing an app using Xamarin Forms and I have an issue I was hoping someone can help with.

My app contains a screen which has multiple icons that can be pressed which would then open a new screen.

My issue is that if you press the icon twice really fast, the app opens up 2 instances of the same screen (it's not just related to a double press, if you press the icon 6 times very fast it will open up 6 duplicate screens).  Pressing the Back button, closes the top screen to reveal the duplicate screen underneath.  Pressing the Back button again navigates you back to the original screen.

This issue seems to occur on any screen within my app so I'm hoping other people will have experienced it and know of a solution to prevent duplicate screens being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in TapEvents.

My hack is, in the code-behind, have a bool variable `_canTap`.

Inside the method you are calling to push new page, first you check if `canTap`, then set to false, and only set to true after navigating to another page. This way all taps will be disregarded.

Example:

```
 private bool _canTap = true;


public void YourMethod()
{
    if(_canTap)
    {
         _canTap = false;
         YourMethodToNavigate();
         _canTap = true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Icon_Pressed method add this,

```
this.IsEnabled = false;

await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage());

this.IsEnabled = true;
```

It disables the page until the current Icon pressed event is finished

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem with Xamarin apps. I've used a private variable combined with a `try-finally` pattern to solve this. Ex:

```
bool allowTap = true;

public void ButtonTapped()
{
    try
    {
        if(allowTap)
        {
            allowTap = false;
            // Do whatever...
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        allowTap = true;
    }
}
```

The `finally` makes sure allowTap gets set back to true no matter what happens, short of a complete crash. Note that you can also use a `catch` block between the `try` and `finally` blocks to grab any errors if needed.